# Can I interrupt Celery task by another one?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a view in my project that runs a Celery task on user registration. The task checks if user is verified 3 days after registration:

```
@shared_task()
def delete_user_if_not_verified(user_pk: int):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
    email = user.email
    if not user.is_verified:
        user.delete()
        return f'Delete {email} user'
```

My idea is that this task will be interrupted with another one in case if user verified much earlier, right after registration, for example. I've already figured out how to catch changes in database but I just don't know how can I pass task or user id of the user that verified to delete_user_if_not_verified(). Is this possible or this idea is bad and I'll be good with one task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to create a periodic task: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

See that you adjust your database query to your model. Goal is to select all users that have registered until three days ago and are inactive. Afterwards just delete them

```
@periodic_task(
    bind=True,
    run_every=(crontab(minute=0, hour=0))
)
def delete_not_registered_users(self):
    User.objects.filter(created__lt=datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=3)), is_verified=False).delete()
```